# Remove {} from list to use it on SOQL string in Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using a list in my soql, the list is formed with different names of countries from set of seperate records. 
The list(name - countryList) is of format.

```
    List<ABC__c> rlList = ABC__c.getall().values();
    Set<String> countryList = new Set<String>(); 
    for (ABC__c pr : rlList){     
        String countrywithquotes = '\''+ pr.Country__c + '\'';
        countryList.add(countrywithquotes);

    }
```

countryList - {'India', 'USA','UK','China','Brazil'}

Query String in Apex Code -

```
String qry = 'Select  Id, country__c from BDC__c where Country__c IN ('+ countryList +') '
```

In debug log , the SOQL query string produces a query like below -

```
Select  Id, Country__c  from ABC__c where Country__c  IN ({'India', 'USA','UK','China','Brazil'})
```

Please let me know a way to remove the extra { character so that the SOQL can be executed.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of [Query exception - Unexpected token '{'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178053/2995).

Comment: Or maybe [Dynamic Query - System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found '.'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147580/2995)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can simply do:**

```
List<ABC__c> rlList = ABC__c.getall().values();
    Set<String> countryList = new Set<String>(); 
    for (ABC__c pr : rlList){     
        if(!string.isBlank(pr.Country__c)) countryList.add(pr.Country__c);

    }

String query = 'Select Id From ABC__c Where Country__c In :countryList';
```

**as dynamic queries allow bind variables**

*otherwise*, as an exercise in learning String methods You can do something like this the generate the string you need when you cannot use a bind variable:

```
List<ABC__c> rlList = ABC__c.getall().values();
    Set<String> countryList = new Set<String>(); 
    for (ABC__c pr : rlList){     
        String countrywithquotes = '\''+ pr.Country__c + '\'';
        countryList.add(countrywithquotes);

    }

String query = 'Select Id From ABC__c Where Country__c In (' + 
        string.join(New List<String>(countryList),',') + ')';
```

This will concat the Countries (that already have quotes around them) with a comma

Depending on your idea of simplification and code placement you could also do this:

```
List<ABC__c> rlList = ABC__c.getall().values();
    Set<String> countryList = new Set<String>(); 
    for (ABC__c pr : rlList){     
        countryList.add(pr.Country__c);

    }

String query = 'Select Id From ABC__c Where Country__c In (\'' +
                 string.join(New List<String>(countryList),'\',\'') + '\')';
```

As an aside, not sure what you mean by the comment

> My query in batch class is too big so can not be fit into a single line

As a query does not have to fit into a single line. The below is perfectly valid

```
[
   Select
        Id,
        Name
   From Account
]
```

As long as it is within the brackets. Additionally a dynamic string can be on multiple lines as well.

Comment: I followed the 1st approach - List<ABC__c> rlList = 
String query = 'Select Id From ABC__c Where Country__c In :countryList';  However, getting the error for {} and in debug log i see my query contains country list like -{'India', 'USA','UK','China','Brazil'}

Comment: @CRMGuy - Did you modify the for loop like it have it? If so update your question with your current attempt cause I am confident that the code I posted works just fine

Comment: I am using string.join and that is working.  Thanks for help.

Comment: @CRMGuy - The first example should work just fine as well and is the better pattern. The others are kinda anti patterns of sorts

Answer (score 2):

Do it in this way:

```
for(ABC__c abc: [Select  Id, country__c from ABC__c where Country__c IN: countryList]){
  //process abc record here
}
```

If you concatenate a List in a string then you will always get the {item1, item2, ...} so you should go for the **variable binding**.

Comment: My query in batch class is too big so can not be fit into a single line . Hence using query string. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean you are passing the query string in the `queryLocator` like method which accepts a `String`?

Comment: yes.. i am passing the string on query locator method.

Comment: @CRMGuy Use the countryList variable, as written in this answer. No need to use a string.